# Divide one text file to multiple text file accord to how many string in python

Tags: python

How to divide a text file that have multiple string to many text files. Like this

inside textfile.txt
string 1
string 2
string 3
string 4
string n+1

then divide to multiple textfile and name the txt file to the string inside textfile.txt

string 1.txt
string 2.txt
string 3.txt
string 4.txt

and so on until the the loop of the string stop until n+1

Comment: The format of your input file is unclear -- is each string on a separate line or are the all on one line? If they are all on one line, how are they delimited from one another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will write each line of the input file to a separate output file (if that's what you meant):

```
with open('textfile.txt', 'rt') as inf:
    for linenum, line in enumerate(inf, start=1):
        filename = 'string {}.txt'.format(linenum)
        with open(filename, 'wt') as outf:
            outf.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks its working! And I want to ask. That is only print per line. How to print more? Example 

in textfile.txt
string 1
this is my pen
this is my book

string 2
this is my phone
this is my ...

and in string 1.txt will have this string
this is my pen
this is my book

string 2.txt
this is my phone
this is my ...

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your follow on question. Try editing your question or ask a new one.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open('inputTextFile.txt', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for fileName in reader:
        open(fileName, 'a').close()
```

'a' ensures that if the file already exists and it has some content then it is not overwritten.
This may or may not work depending on the format of your inputTextFile. This is assuming that the strings are delimited by spaces. You can read about csv here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html